# Topology of varieties in a flat family

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space, flatness

I am learning about flat deformations of schemes at the moment. I understand that while it is not immediately clear from the definition why this should be a good definition it turns out that these have many properties that one wants a family of schemes to have. To get the correct picture, I want to ask if my intuition regarding topology is correct: Consider a flat and projective morphism $f: X \to T$ where $T$ is variety over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ and assume that $T(\mathbb{K})$ is connected (in the classical topology). Then my intuition says that things can only change when passing through singular varieties in the family. Here are my concrete questions:

1. Let $X_t$ be smooth for all $t\in T$. Is it true that all $X_t(\mathbb{K})$ are homeomorphic to each other?
2. Let $t_0\in T(\mathbb{K})$ and $Y=X_{t_0}$. Assume that $X_t$ is smooth for every $t\neq t_0$. Let $Y_{sm}$ be the nonsingular locus of $Y$ and assume that the space $Y_{sm}(\mathbb{K})$ is connected. Is it then true that every $X_t(\mathbb{K})$ is connected? (This makes maybe only sense for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Are you asking the question for hypersurfaces in projective spaces or more general?

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear. I am asking in general. Forget about hypersurfaces.

Comment: This is certainly false without some extra hypothesis like $f$ is projective.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking of $f$ being projective. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your questions are quite difficult in the generality you asked them. Certainly this is the case for me, a person without a proper understanding of the flatness condition. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75317/flatness-in-complex-analytic-geometry) is a post from MathOverflow I find useful for me.

> Let $X_t$ be smooth for all $t\in T$. Is it true that all $X_t(\mathbb{K})$ are homeomorphic to each other?

Assume $T$ is irreducible. Using resolution of singularities and base change, I think we can assume $T$ to be smooth. In this situation, since your family is projective, and all the fibers are smooth, I think that this implies that $f$ is a proper submersion, and hence the answer is yes.

> Let $t_0\in T(\mathbb{K})$ and $Y=X_{t_0}$. Assume that $X_t$ is smooth for every $t\neq t_0$. Let $Y_{sm}$ be the nonsingular locus of $Y$ and assume that the space $Y_{sm}(\mathbb{K})$ is connected. Is it then true that every $X_t(\mathbb{K})$ is connected? (This makes maybe only sense for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$.)

My answer considers only the case $K = \mathbb{C}$, complex numbers, and dimension of fibers of $f$ strictly positive with $Y_{sm}$ nonempty. Since $Y_{sm}$ is connected, it is irreducible, and hence $Y$ itself is irreducible. Assume that the generic fiber $X_t$ has $k > 1$ connected components. If we apply the Stein factorization to the map $f$, we get a finite morphism $g: T' \to T$, of degree $k$, and such that $t_0' = g^{-1}(t_0)$ is just one point. But then this point must have multiplicity $k$, which implies that the whole fiber $Y$ is multiple. This contradicts $Y_{sm}$ nonempty.

Maybe one can suppose $\dim T = 1$ in this argument, and then everything is more intuitive.

> Thanks very much! So regarding the second question: This only works over the complex numbers because Stein factorization only works over complex numbers? Would $\dim T =1$ help for the case of $K=\mathbb{R}$?

In the real case, the answer can be negative, as the family of cubic plane curves giving the universal deformation of the nodal cubic shows.

> That I don't understand: If $Y$ is the nodal cubic, then $Y_{sm}(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected. So it doesn't satisfy the assumptions.

Yes, you're right. I just mixed up the real and complex cases. So I can say nothing in the real case.

Comment: Thanks very much! So regarding the second question: This only works over the complex numbers because Stein factorization only works over complex numbers? Would $\textrm{dim} T=1$ help for the case of $K=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That I don't understand: If $Y$ is the nodal cubic, then $Y_{sm}(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected. So it doesn't satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: @Hans I have updated my answer.

Comment: Just a comment: your claim "and so I think that it's a smooth submersion" is true. As you probably know this follows from the infinitesimal lifting criterion (since you can compute the algebraic or analytic tangent spaces the same). You can also think that it etale locally over the base looks like affine space (over the base) and since etale morphisms in the complex topology are local biholomorphisms this says that locally it looks like the trivial cover. This is what I assume you were referencing the (I don't remember the name theorem) that says smooth proper submersions are locally trivial

Comment: fibrations. (EDIT: Found the name: Ehresmann's Theorem).

Comment: @AlexYoucis Ah I see, thanks! (That's cleared up some nuts and bolts in my head...)